# Email Send Definition Publication List via SendDefinitionList

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, publicationlist, send-definition

I hope I am just missing something that is right in front of my nose, but I keep getting an error when creating this send definition.  It works smashingly when I remove the attempt to put in a Publication list, but when I place in the SendDefinitionList containing the Pub List, it errors.

Error:

```
<StatusMessage>The send definition has the following 2 error(s):
  The list is not specified for send definition list array element 2.
The list with ID =  was not found for send definition list array element 2.
</StatusMessage>
```

SOAP code causing issues: (added in sample ID/CustKey in code below)

```
<SendDefinitionList>
  <ID>123456</ID>
  <DataSourceTypeID>OptOutList</DataSourceTypeID>
  <SendDefinitionListType>OptOutList</SendDefinitionListType>
</SendDefinitionList>
```

I checked everything and the correct [DataSourceTypeID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/datasourcetypeenum.htm) and [SendDefinitionListType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/senddefinitionlisttypeenum.htm) should be set to OptOutList - and I pulled the ID and customerkey from another call, so I know those are accurate, but the error makes it seem like that ID does not exist.

Example RetrieveResponseMsg when grabbing the Pub List info:

```
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
    <RequestID>f7db0ded-eca4-4b09-b132-63c6587506a1</RequestID>
    <Results xsi:type="List">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
        <ID>123456</ID>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
        <CustomerKey>My Pub Customer Key</CustomerKey>
        <Type>Private</Type>
        <ListClassification>PublicationList</ListClassification>
    </Results>
</RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify the ID of the list inside List tag to define that you are looking for a list, for example:

```
<SendDefinitionList>
  <List>
      <ID>...</ID>
  </List>
  <DataSourceTypeID>OptOutList</DataSourceTypeID>
  <SendDefinitionListType>OptOutList</SendDefinitionListType>
</SendDefinitionList>
```